# How to pass variable value from command parameter and use it in with_items:?

Tags: ansible

For me the below code is working - 
`with_items: "{{ groups['mlpoc'] }}"` but instead of hardcoded `mlpoc` I want to pass it in a variable as a parameter.
Say the command parameter is `mlhosts=mlpoc` and I want to use the variable instead of hardcoded value, something like - 
`with_items: "{{ groups['{{ mlhosts }}'] }}"` but it throws error. Is it even possible to pass a dynamic value to groups ?
Here is my code -

```
- hosts: dbsrd3510
  user: '{{ mluser }}'
  gather_facts: no
  no_log: false
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch source list from clients
      with_items: "{{ groups['mlpoc'] }}" 
      shell: rsync -av /MLbackup/{{ pkg }} {{ mluser }}@{{ item }}:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Add a line to a file if the file does not exist, without passing regexp
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: " {{ groups[group_name] }} "
```

And you can test the above changes using,

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -e group_name="all"
```

Comment: Awesome. basically with_items is a constraint to put. This worked for me
shell: rsync -av /MLbackup/{{ pkg }} {{ mlupguser }}@{{ item }}:/tmp/
      with_items: " {{ groups[group_name] }} "

Comment: @bosari, That's Nice, if this fixed your issue, please accept the answer to mark this question as answered. Happy to help :)